# Cypress delete screenshots of failure if they are 30 days old

Tags: cypress

my config is set to `trashAssetsBeforeRuns: FALSE` however the `cypress/screenshots` gets packed over time.

This is mainly for Jenkins because the Cypress Run command wipes all previous screenshots of failures once they start to pass again. That way I don't know what was failing previously.

I know it can be done using Jenkins itself but, is there a way to configure Cypress to delete the content of `cypress/screenshots` that are over 1 month old?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom script or use cronjob to do that for you
By using JS you can do a code using NodeJS:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const screenshotsDirectory = 'cypress/screenshots';
const maxAgeInDays = 30;

const deleteOldScreenshots = async () => {
  try {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(screenshotsDirectory);

    const currentDate = new Date();
    const maxAgeDate = currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - maxAgeInDays);

    files.forEach(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(screenshotsDirectory, file);
      const fileStat = await fs.promises.stat(filePath);

      if (fileStat.isFile() && fileStat.ctime < maxAgeDate) {
        await fs.promises.unlink(filePath);
        console.log(`Deleted old screenshot: ${file}`);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred while deleting old screenshots:', error);
  }
};

deleteOldScreenshots();
```

Sure you need to install `fs` module